# How does spring boot know which property file to use based on environment

Tags: java, spring-boot, model-view-controller

I have 4 files in my project:

- application.properties
- application-dev.properties
- application-qa.properties
- application-prod.properties

application.properties has a property spring.profiles.active = @active.profile@

When running on local, it uses application-dev.properties file. But in UAT and Prod, it uses respective property files. My question is how does spring boot know to use dev when im running in local and and qa in uat and prod in prod?

What does @active.profile@ mean?

Answer (score 0):

This is decided by the "profiles" variable. This is a `Set<String>`.

The exact way spring detect the profiles depends on the way you run your application.

The most common way is through the System Parameter: `-Dspring.profiles.active=dev`. So I assume somwhere in your production enviroment this variable gets set.

Alternativelly, if you run your spring app via a builder, you can define the profiles explicitly (code is in kotlin):

```
SpringApplicationBuilder(MyApp::class.java)
    .profiles(*profiles)
    .run(*args)
```

Check this article for more info: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles